# How to start RAID array?

Tags: data-recovery, raid, mdadm

a few months ago two volumes in my Synology DiskStation 412+ NAS crashed and until now I am still unable to recover the data but I am motivated and won't give up.

I am able to see the hard drives (sda and sdc) under "disks" in Ubuntu but I am unable to mount the raid volume.

It also detects the RAID array but it is not running.

If I want to start it, then it says "No array found in config file or automatically"
When I try the command "sudo mdadm -A /dev/sda /dev/sdc" then it says it exists but it is not an md array.

At this point I don't know what to do. Any help will be appreciated. You can find all screenshots [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ksrsd92n9vooa6i/AACG7TLXDgFFhK4U9eqKatW9a?dl=0)

Since I am new to this forum I am not allowed to upload pictures or add more than 2 links so I created a photo album on Dropbox with all screenshots.

Thanks for your help in advance! I hope I can recover my data soon!

Comment: How about this: http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Linux/Q_26975100.html